# Keyframe loop animation resulting in compilation error

Tags: css, loops, less, keyframe

I'm trying to create Less loop, to animate the coins left and top position with CSS. I've created some Less mixin that creates a keyframes and assign it to current element, but I'm getting the Less error.
Can someone say, what's wrong with this code?

```
.boom (@index) when (@index > 0){
   @keyframes boom@index {
       0% {
          top: 50%;
          left: 50%;
       }
       50%{
          top: random(2500)+px;
          left: random(2500)+px;
       }
   }
   .coin:nth-child(@{@]index}){
        left: unit(@{i}* 10, px);
        animation-duration: 2.6s;
        animation-name: boom-@{i};
        animation-direction: alternate;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  }
  .boom(@index - 1);
}
.boom(5);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are a couple of typo errors in the code given in question as `@{i}` is used in a few places. I assume they were intended to be `@{index}`.

Other than that, the following were the corrections:

- When you give `@keyframes boom@index`, first of all you have to use the variable in the form `@{}` because the variable is being used in a selector (sort of). This is to avoid Less compiler treating it like it is a CSS `@` rule.
- After that there is a typo error again in the line `.coin:nth-child(@{@]index})`. There is an extra `@` and a `]` brace.
- Finally, even if we ignore the `@{i}` and `@{index}` confusion, the code `animation-name: boom-@{i};` will cause a problem because when you try to concatenate a variable with a string without enclosing them in quotes it would produce an error.
- **Note:** `random(2500)+px` will not cause any compilation errors but there is no built-in `random()` function in Less and `+` is not used for string concatenation (unless you are using LessPHP like mentioned by seven-phases-max in comments). I think you were probably looking for something like `` unit(`Math.random(2500)`,px) ``.

```
.boom (@index) when (@index > 0){
    @keyframes ~"boom@{index}" {
       0% {
          top: 50%;
          left: 50%;
       }
       50%{
          top: random(2500)+px;
          left: random(2500)+px;
       }
   }
    .coin:nth-child(@{index}){
        left: unit(@index * 10, px);
        animation-duration: 2.6s;
        animation-name: ~"boom-@{index}";
        animation-direction: alternate;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  }
  .boom(@index - 1);
}
.boom(5);
```

Comment: Oh God, how did I miss that @seven-phases-max. Should be because it didn't cause a compile error. By the way is there really a `random()` built-in function?

Comment: No, there's no `random` too, so I wonder where Danis collected so many misprinted ideas he thought to work (for the `1+px` I thought she could probably use `lessphp` which does allow `+` for string concatenation, but then it does not support any kind of interpolation in the `@keyframes`).

Comment: I just searched how to create a loop with less , and math operations in less and use one of the firsts results. Actually, I'm new in Less, so, please don't  judge strictly))

Comment: @Danis: Ofcourse not pal :) Everybody starts from scratch and there is nothing wrong in asking questions. Hope the answer helped you solve the problem. If it did, please consider accepting and/or upvoting it.

Comment: by the way I'm getting `invalid keyframes name` error

Comment: @Danis: That's probably because there is a hyphen in the value provided for `animation-name` property but in `@keyframes` it is missing. Remove/add the hyphen as appropriate.

Comment: No, I removed the hyphen. the problem is that the less doesn't want to concat string and variable, because when I write the name only, it works

Comment: @Danis Are you using LessPHP like mentioned seven-phases-max' comment? If yes then you can't use interpolation as mentioned in his comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88009/discussion-between-danis-and-harry).